# Ansible: Skip line in loop if attribute does not exist

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a task that prints lines to a CSV file. Each host will have a number of variables named `section_1`, `section_2`, `section_3`, `section_4`; `section_1` may or may not have a value.

```yaml
- name: Print Section to CSV File
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ output_file }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
    create: true
    state: present
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop:
    - { line: '{{ section_1 }},{{ section_2 }}' }
    - { line: '{{ section_3 }},{{ section_4 }}' }
```

I'm trying to figure out **How to skip the first line if `section_1` does not have a value and move to the next line to `section_3`?**

As of right now it will error out if `section_1` does not have a value. I've also tried to add `| default()` to the `loop` such as:

```yaml
  loop:
    - { line: '{{ section_1 | default() }},{{ section_2 }}' }
    - { line: '{{ section_3 }},{{ section_4 }}' }
```

This will just create a blank space for `section_1` and will print out `{{ section_2 }}` instead of skipping the entire line.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> ***How to skip the first line if `s1` does not have a value and move to the next line to `s3`?***

Although Ansible isn't a programming language and there seems to be a lot of information missing regarding your Use Case, the variables and so on, such is possible in example in the following way

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    s1: 
    s2: 2
    s3: 3
    s4: 4

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "line: {{ vars['s' ~ item] }},{{ vars['s' ~ (item + 1)] }}"
    when: vars['s' ~ item]
    loop: "{{ range(1, 5, 2) | list }}"
```

The minimal example playbook will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 'line: 3,4'
```

or if set

```yaml
  vars:

    s1: 1
    s2: 2
    s3: 3
    s4: 4
```

into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 'line: 1,2'
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 'line: 3,4'
```

The solution seems to be for me, instead of iterating over lines, use an iterator and evaluate the variable names dynamically only when the variable has content. The creation of the line content becomes then trivial and the whole approach generic.

**Credits To**

- [How to evaluate a dynamic variable name in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375054/6771046)

**Further Documentation**

- [How do I access a variable name programmatically?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-variable-name-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"Skip line in loop if attribute **does not exist**."*

A: Instead of lines' list

```yaml
  - { line: '{{ section_1 | default() }},{{ section_2 }}' }
  - { line: '{{ section_3 }},{{ section_4 }}' }
```

create a list of the sections

```yaml
  sections: [section_1, section_2, section_3, section_4]
```

Automate the list if there are many consecutive sections. For example, the declaration below gives the same result

```yaml
  sections: "{{ ['section']|product(range(1,5))|map('join', '_') }}"
```

Iterate the list by 2 items. Get the values and set the default to *None*. Skip the line if any section doesn't exist

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ val0 }},{{ val1 }}"
      loop: "{{ sections|batch(2) }}"
      when: val0 and val1
      vars:
        val0: "{{ lookup('vars', item.0, default=None) }}"
        val1: "{{ lookup('vars', item.1, default=None) }}"
```

gives (if *section_1* does not exist)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['section_1', 'section_2']) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=['section_3', 'section_4']) => 
  msg: value_3,value_4
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    section_2: value_2
    section_3: value_3
    section_4: value_4

#   sections: [section_1, section_2, section_3, section_4]
    sections: "{{ ['section']|product(range(1,5))|map('join', '_') }}"
    

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: sections|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ val0 }},{{ val1 }}"
      loop: "{{ sections|batch(2) }}"
      when: val0 and val1
      vars:
        val0: "{{ lookup('vars', item.0, default=None) }}"
        val1: "{{ lookup('vars', item.1, default=None) }}"
```